# In search of an early picture of Max Dehn

Tags: ho.history-overview

I am trying to find a copy of a picture "Mathematische Gesellschaft: 
Group Portrait, Faculty, University of Göttingen (1899)."

This picture was published by Springer-Verlag as a poster in 1985,
but Springer has been unable to find a copy for me. I also sent an email
query to the Mathematics library at Göttingen, but received no response.

So, as a last resort, I would like to ask whether any MO members have
access to a copy of the picture. I want to use it in a talk about Max 
Dehn I am giving in Frankfurt in June, because Max Dehn appears in the 
picture.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the poster is right on the other side of the hall in front of my office. Here is a picture of Dehn that I've made with my phone:

[image: Max Dehn]

I could make a better picture on Monday if that would be helpful...

**Edit:** Ok, my next better camera produced this picture:

[image: Max Dehn]

Probably that's already near the best you can get because you can already see the halftoning effects pretty clear...

Comment: Thanks, Dirk, this is wonderful! If it is possible to make a sharper
picture I would appreciate it, but this is already good enough for
me to use.

Comment: Thanks for the second attempt; I'm now convinced that the first
one is close to best possible. Back in 1899, photographs were
usually not very sharp, and Dehn was only a small part of a large 
group picture.

Comment: @Dirk: Would you be so kind as to share a photo of the whole poster with me? Best regards...

Comment: Sorry, the building where this picture was has meanwhile been completely remodeled. While my office is in this building again, the poster is not. I don't know where it is now…